# Computing vs printing

Tags: performance, floating-point, console.log

In my program, I made few modifications for performance improvement.

First, I undid some 3D point computations as it was a repetitive computation.

Second, I undid some print statements.

What I observe is that second change substantially improved the performance, while first one not so much.

Does it mean computations involving floating numbers are much less expensive than printing out some data to console? Is not floating point mathematics considered to be highly computation extensive?

Comment: Yes, console output is *extremely* slow.

Comment: Yes, I/O is a lot slower than floating point operations. If you want to print something try doing it only every so often. EG. if you are printing in a loop, print only every 10000 iterations instead.

Comment: Why this downvote?How does this question break any rules?

Comment: @Mandroid: it doesn't. It is sometimes hard to understand why people downvote. Don't expect an explanation.

Comment: In English, “undid” means to have reversed something. I think you mean to write that you “did some print … computations” and “did some print statements,” not that you “undid” them.

Comment: No. I meant that I removed those operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is often more expensive than integer arithmetic, in terms of processor cycles and/or the space required for it in the silicon of processors and/or the energy required for it. However, printing is generally much more expensive.

Typical performance for floating-point additions or multiplications might be a latency of four processor cycles, compared to one for integer additions or multiplications.

Formatting output requires many instructions. Converting numbers to decimal requires dividing or performing table-lookups or executing other algorithms. The characters generated to represent a number must be placed in a buffer. Checks must be performed to ensure that internal buffers are not overflowed. When a buffer is full, or a printing operation is complete and must be sent to the output device (rather than just merely held in a buffer for future operations), then an operating system call must be performed to transfer the data from user memory to some input-output driver. Even simple in-buffer formatting operations may take hundreds of cycles, and printing that requires interaction with the file system or other devices may take thousands of cycles. (The actual upper limit is infinite, since printing may have to wait for some physical device to become ready. But even if all the activity of a particular operation is inside the computer itself, a print operation may take thousands of cycles.)